# Requiring module in Rspec in rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm trying to include additional Devise helpers in Rspec but am receiving the following error:

```
rails_helper.rb:56:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ControllerMacros (NameError)
```

Line 56 in rails_helpers.rb is the config.include ControllerMacros line that I have. I've tried to solve this with the solutions posted in other SO posts but can't seem to get this to work. I understand this might be a require order issue but haven't been able to sort out the right order.

**rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'devise'
ctiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

**spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_business
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:business]
      business = FactoryGirl.create(:business)
      buisness.confirm!
      sign_in business
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/business_account_controller_spec.rb**
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

```
describe BusinessAccountController do
  login_business

  it "should have current user" do
    expect(subject).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to require it in your `rails_helper`. I place all of my modules in /spec/support and then put `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }` at the top of my `rails_helper`

Comment: @CWitty That was the solution. You can post that as a formal answer if you want? If not I'll respond later with the solution you shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `require` it in your `rails_helper`. I place all of my modules in `/spec/support` and then put `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }` at the top of my `rails_helper`